# How to create and use a custom UIPasteboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

Need to copy a text to pasteboard but not general one, apple docs doesn't refer how to use a created one

Answer (score 1):

Custom `UIPasteboard` can created by

```
UIPasteboard(name: <UIPasteboard.Name>, create: <Bool>)
```

Here the name parameter will be name of the pasteboard through which you can retrieve it later and the create parameter takes a bool that tells to create one or not if a pasteboard does not exist by that name.

For more details refer to- [pasteboardWithName:create:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622074-pasteboardwithname)